# Batch : Read only a Paragraph and Repeat for another paragraph from txt file

Tags: file, batch-file, text, windows-7, command-prompt

I am trying to make a simple question game with batch. like this :

```
------- This is Ascii --------

1. This is First Question
   a. this is option a
   b. this is option b
   c. this is option c
   d. this is option d

Put Your Answer > [a/b/c/d]
```

And what I want is :

I want my game to load the question from text file because the question is quite a lot

This is my Question.txt file example :

```
1. This is First Question
   a. This is option a
   b. This is option b
   c. This is option c
   d. This is option d

2. This is Second Question
   a. This is option a
   b. This is option b
   c. This is option c
   d. This is option d

3. This is Third Question
   a. This is option a
   b. This is option b
   c. This is option c
   d. This is option d
```

I was experimenting around with FOR command etc... and I didn't figure it out about main menu and other thing, I got my own. My problem is only this.
Can you figure it out for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

Make sure your `question.txt` has a blank line at the bottom, and try this:

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,3) do (
   echo.
   type "question.txt" | findrepl "^%%a. " /e:"^$"
   pause
)
```

Another way of using this code is like this

```
type "question.txt" | findrepl "^1. " /e:"^$"
pause
type "question.txt" | findrepl "^2. " /e:"^$"
pause
type "question.txt" | findrepl "^3. " /e:"^$"
pause
type "question.txt" | findrepl "^4. " /e:"^$"
pause
```

Comment: can you describe to me how to use findrepl more ? i mean i didn't understand what (| findrepl "^4. " /e:"^$" ) is... thanks you before

Comment: `^` inside the quotes means to take it as the start of the line.  So it is searching for `1. ` at the start of a line with the following space, and then searches for the end `/e:` which is the next blank line that has no characters on it. `$` means the end of the line and so ^$ means use the start and end of the line with nothing in between.  These are called `regular expressions`.  Each term is the same with the search term starting with the different number.